# Creating a new column by manipulating other columns by multiple groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example_1 <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep(101,4), rep(102, 4)),
  condition = rep(c("selfrefneg", "selfrefneg", "selfimmneg", "selfimmneg"),2),
  event = c("neg_self_1", "neg_self_2", "neg_self_2", "neg_self_1","neg_other_1", "neg_other_2", "neg_other_2", "neg_other_1"),
  rating = c(3,3,4,4,3,3,5,5)
)
```

Edited dataframe:

```
example_2 <- data.frame(
  subject = c(rep(101,4), rep(102, 4)),
  condition = c("selfrefneg", "selfrefneg", "selfimmneg", "selfimmneg", "socrefneg", "socrefneg", "socimmneg", "socimmneg"),
  event = c("neg_self_1", "neg_self_2", "neg_self_2", "neg_self_1","neg_other_1", "neg_other_2", "neg_other_2", "neg_other_1"),
  rating = c(3,3,4,4,3,3,5,5)
)
```

I want to mutate the dataframe such that I have a column for the difference in `rating` by `event` and `subject`, where the difference is the rating for

- *`selfimmneg - selfrefneg`* and
- *`socimmneg - socrefneg`*.

This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  subject = c(101, 101, 102, 102),
  event = c("neg_self_1", "neg_self_2", "neg_other_1", "neg_other_2"),
  rating_diff = c(1,1,2,2)
)
```

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match()` + `diff()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  summarise(rating_diff = coalesce(
    diff(rating[match(c("selfrefneg", "selfimmneg"), condition)]),
    diff(rating[match(c("socrefneg", "socimmneg"), condition)])
  ), .by = c(subject, event))

#   subject       event rating_diff
# 1     101  neg_self_1           1
# 2     101  neg_self_2           1
# 3     102 neg_other_1           2
# 4     102 neg_other_2           2
```

- Note that using `match()` is much safer to consider the order and completeness of 4 conditions in each group.

---

Comment: Thanks @Darren Tsai! I have edited my dataframe with a new question -- how may I edit your solution with this updated dataframe to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize` with some indexing:

```
example %>%
  summarize(rating_diff = rating[condition == "selfimmneg"] - rating[condition == "selfrefneg"],
            .by = c(event, subject))
```

Output:

```
        event subject rating_diff
1  neg_self_1     101           1
2  neg_self_2     101           1
3 neg_other_1     102           2
4 neg_other_2     102           2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example |>
  arrange(desc(condition)) |>
  summarise(rating_diff = diff(rating), .by = c(event, subject))

#         event subject rating_diff
# 1  neg_self_1     101           1
# 2  neg_self_2     101           1
# 3 neg_other_1     102           2
# 4 neg_other_2     102           2
```